# Как сделать наверху полоску как в фейсбук?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать наверху полоску как в фейсбук?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала выучить html и css.

А затем сделать так:

1.Создать 2 файла: index.html (по этой ссылке его каркас: [здесь каркас](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)), styles.css.

2.Подключить в index.html через тег link css-стили т.е styles.css.

3.Открыть styles.css и там написать:

```
* 
{ 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
}

#topNavLine 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: #000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 9999; 
}
```

4.Открыть файл index.html
между тегами **`<body> вот сюда </body>`** вставить наш div(он же блок) со следующим кодом:

```
<div id="topNavLine">здесь содержимое твоей полоски.</div>
```

Comment: Наверное главный вопрос был о position: fixed <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp">position: fixed</a>

Comment: Точно!Самое главное забыл добавить :).Спасибо за поправку!

Answer (score 1):

Если надо, чтобы она торчала сверху всё время то к ай ди topNavLine надо добавить:

```
#topNavLine   
{  
    width: 100%;  
    height: 40px;  
    background: #000;  
    position:fixed;  
    top:0px;  
    left:0px;    
    z-index:100;  
}
```

Comment: Извините за вопрос.Как называется новая функция хроника только по-другом?